# I need help properly implementing a booking scheduler and availability in Django

Tags: django, forms, django-rest-framework, frontend, backend

This question has been asked many times before on StackOverflow and in the Django forums, but none of the answers I've found are appropriate or complete enough for my situation.

**First, the brief:**

I'm creating a web application for a car rental business. In addition to helping them organize and centralize their fleet, it will also help them collect orders directly from customers. As with most rentals, the logistics of it all can be somewhat confusing.

Someone may place an order for a car today (December 12th) but actually take the car over the Christmas to New Year's period.

A renter may borrow a car for just two days, and then extend the booking at the last minute. When this happens (often very frequently), the business usually has to scramble to find another one for a different customer who was scheduled to get that car the next day.

Adding to that, an individual car can only be rented to one client at a time, so it can't have multiple bookings for the same period.

Most answers advocate for a simple approach that looks like this:

**models.py**

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, ...)
    start_date = models.dateField(...)
    end_date = models.dateField(...)
    is_available = models.booleanField(default=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
import datetime

from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from . import models

class PlaceOrderForm(forms.Form):
    """Initial order forms for customers."""
    start_date = forms.DateField(help_text='When do you want the car?')
    end_date = forms.DateField(help_text='When will you return the car?')

    def clean_data(self, date):
        data = self.cleaned_data(date)

        # Check that start date is not in the past
        if data < datetime.date.today():
            raise ValidationError(_('Invalid date: Start in past.'))

        # Ensure that start date is not today (to avoid last_minute bookings.)
        if data == datetime.date.today():
            raise ValidationError(_('Invalid date: Please reserve your car at least 24 hours in advance.'))

        return data

    cleaned_start_date = clean_data(start_date)
    cleaned_end_date = clean_data(end_date)
```

('_' is for )

The booking has a start_date and an end_date. When a *current* date is within the start_date and end_date, the car is marked as unavailable. If the boolean field is_available (not represented in forms.py above) is set to "False", the car is unavailable completely.

Again, because of the unique nature of car rentals, this may be a problem. Some people book a car for six months, and others book it for two days. If someone wants a long-term rental but there's another short interlude during their expected duration, this validation would prevent them from placing the order completely!

But this is a problem: Going back to the rental model, someone may be booking a car in the future. A car that's unavailable *now* should still be able to be reserved for a future date.

Adding to that, an individual car can only be rented to one person at a time, so it can't have multiple bookings for the same period. Again, because of the unique nature of car rentals, this may be a problem. Some people book a car for six months, and others book it for two days. If someone wants a long-term rental but there's another short interlude during their expected duration, this validation would prevent them from placing the order completely!

So if a conflict arises, rather than blocking the booking entirely (which, again, would be a bad UX decision), it should notify the business so they can assign another car and plan ahead.

Other clients should not be able to book it *for the time in which it is borrowed*, but they should be able to book it for other times when it is free.

So if someone places an order now for, let's say the 24-31st of December. Those days should be blocked off. However, another person should be able to book it from today to the 23rd, and from the 31st onwards. And if the person renting it should extend, it should notify the rental business so they can assign another car to the user well in advance.

**Possible idea to move forward**
The core assumption in all those answers is that the booking unavailability has to be handled in **Django** itself, in the backend. However, I'm building this project with REST framework, and will use a Js based front-end (currently learning Javascript for this purpose).

I think that this would be better handled in a more holistic way with the in-built form validation and save functions.

The workflow would go something like this:

1. The User selects a car and selects the start and end dates from a drop-down calendar on the website.
2. The form will then check to see if the absolute basic checks (can't book a car in the past) are fine. If those work, then the order is placed and saved in the database.
3. If there's a scheduling conflict, the order is **not blocked**, but passed to the business that can assign them a different car for the period. (Generally, people don't care much for receiving particular cars--mostly the price, space and the fuel economy. Everything else is interchangeable.
4. Once that happens, the deposit can be collected, and the order can be set in the system.

Anyhow, that's my preliminary idea that would bring together the best of all worlds
and create a great experience for both the business and customer.

So my question is: How could this actually be set up? What would need to be on the front-end and what would go in the back-end? I'm learning programming as I go, so this may be simple, but I've been struggling with this for a week, I would appreciate any help on this!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have two processes - the customer order and the car assignment. You need to plan out your data structure and then your process flow.  This will help you get things straight before you start.

Models

Using (Brackets) for foreign keys, Customer_order collects things like:

```
Customer(User)
desired_start_date
desired_end_date
car_type - this could be many fields
```

A car model

```
car_type 
rental (many to many Rental with through table Rental)
```

A rental model

```
car (Car)
customer_order(Customer_order)
start_date
end_date
```

We have kept the rental model with its own start and end dates as the user may change their desired period but it shouldn't change the rental dates without checking if others exist in that time period for that car.

So the flow should go:

```
user passes js validation and form submitted to backend
backend checks for car availability based on type and dates
   if available, creates rental
   if not available, alert user and passes to staff

if a user changes a rental period (via an edit screen for existing customer_orders)
   backend checks for same car availability based on existing rentals
   if not available, alert user and pass to staff
```

You'd also create a staff only view, that lists customer_orders that can't be matched (without rental models) along with cars of the requested type that don't have rentals for that period.

Seeing as you have that view, it strikes me your backend process could use something similar to also look for and assign a different car of the same type automatically if you wanted to extend the availability check process, notifying staff it has occurred, while only referring back to staff if that type of car is unavailable.

Actually programming all this is left as an exercise for the reader.